# How to check two POS tags are in the same category in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

Like the title says, how can I check two POS tags are in the same category?

For example,

```
go -> VB
goes -> VBZ
```

These two words are both verbs. Or,

```
bag -> NN
bags -> NNS
```

These two are both nouns.
So my question is that whether there exists any function in NLTK to check if two given tags are in the same category?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the simple case first: Your corpus is tagged with the Brown tagset (that's what it looks like), and you'd be happy with the simple tags defined in the nltk's ["universal" tagset](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html#tab-universal-tagset): `., ADJ, ADP, ADV, CONJ, DET, NOUN, NUM, PRON, PRT, VERB, X`, where the dot stands for "punctuation". In this case, simply load the nltk's map and use it with your data:

```
tagmap = nltk.tag.mapping.tagset_mapping("en-brown", "universal")
if tagmap[tag1] == tagmap[tag2]:
    print("The two words have the same part of speech")
```

If that's not your use case, you'll need to *manually* decide on a mapping from each individual tag to the simplified category you want to assign it to. If you are working with the Brown corpus tagset, you can see the tags and their meanings [here,](http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/brown.html) or from within python like this:

```
print(nltk.help.brown_tagset())
```

Study your tags and define a dictionary that maps each POS tag to your chosen category; people sometimes find it useful to just group Brown corpus tags by their first two letters, putting together "NN", "NN$", "NNS-HL", etc. You could create this particular mapping automatically like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
alltags = set(t for w, t in brown.tagged_words())
tagmap = dict(t[:2] for t in alltags)
```

Then you can customize this map according to your needs; e.g., to put all punctuation tags together in the category ".":

```
for tag in tagmap:
    if not tag.isalpha():
        tagmap[tag] = "."
```

Once your `tagmap` is to your liking, use it like the one I imported from the `nltk`.

Finally, you might find it convenient to retag your entire corpus in one go, so that you can simply compare the assigned tags. If `corpus` is a list of tagged sentences in the format of the nltk's `<corpus>.tagged_sents()` command (so *not* a corpus reader object), you can retag everything like this:

```
newcorpus = []
for sent in corpus:
    newcorpus.append( [ (w, tagmap[t]) for w, t in sent ] )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can tag with a [`universal` tagset](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html#reading-tagged-corpora):

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

s = "I go. He goes. This bag is brown. These bags are brown."

d = defaultdict(list)
for sent in sent_tokenize(s):
    text = word_tokenize(sent)
    for value, tag in pos_tag(text, tagset='universal'):
        d[tag].append(value)

pprint(dict(d))
```

Prints:

```
{'.': ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
 'ADJ': ['brown'],
 'DET': ['This', 'These'],
 'NOUN': ['bag', 'bags'],
 'PRON': ['I', 'He'],
 'VERB': ['go', 'goes', 'is', 'brown', 'are']}
```

Note how `bag` and `bags` fall into `NOUN` category and `go` and `goes` fall into `VERB`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a good method, but my situation is a little bit different. The information I get is a set of tags. I need to cluster them into different sets.